# Keras model consistently underestimates the target

Tags: python, keras, predict

I  don't understand why my keras model is under-estimating the target. I include the minimal example below. If I simplify the model architecture, the predictions are closer to the true one. But what I confuse is if the complex model overfits, why isn't the predictions be extremely close to the training true value but off systematically like that? (The plot is for training data)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def create_dataset(num_series=1, num_steps=1000, period=500, mu=1, sigma=0.3):
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=(num_series, num_steps))
    sin_minumPi_Pi = np.sin(np.tile(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, period), int(num_steps / period)))
    sin_Zero_2Pi = np.sin(np.tile(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, period), int(num_steps / period)))
    pattern = np.concatenate((np.tile(sin_minumPi_Pi.reshape(1, -1),
                                      (int(np.ceil(num_series / 2)),1)),
                              np.tile(sin_Zero_2Pi.reshape(1, -1),
                                      (int(np.floor(num_series / 2)), 1))
                             ),
                             axis=0
                            )

    target = noise + pattern
    return target[0]
avail=create_dataset(mu=5)

window_size = 7
def getdata(data,window_size):
    X,y = np.array([1]*window_size),np.array([])

    for i in range(window_size, len(data)):
        X = np.vstack((X,data[i-window_size:i]))
        y = np.append(y,data[i:i+1])

    return X[1:],y

X,y = getdata(avail,window_size)

def train_model(X,y,a_dim=100,epoch=50,batch_size=32,d=0.2):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(a_dim,activation='relu',input_dim=X.shape[1]))
    model.add(Dropout(d))
    model.add(Dense(a_dim,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(d))
    model.add(Dense(a_dim,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(d))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=epoch,batch_size=batch_size,  verbose=2)
    return model

model = train_model(X,y)

plt.plot(model.predict(X)[:,0])
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because your model has been built for this behaviour.
For a model is the main purpose to get an optimized function which fits any unseen data as well as possible. Aming this, your model starts to learn from training samples. The problem is, that during the training process your model tends to overfit on your training samples loosing its generalization ability i.e. to perform well on unseen data.

To avoid this, we use some technics, one of them is **dropout**.
You used it as well:

```
model.add(Dropout(d))
```

with the default parameter `d=0.2`:

```
def train_model(X,y,a_dim=100,epoch=50,batch_size=32,d=0.2):
```

As I wrote above this is to avoid overfit on your training data and that is why your model constantly overestimate it, but get a better estimation to unseen data.

Passing other `dropout` value to your `train_model()` function you will get better fitting to your train data:

```
model = train_model(X, y, d=0.0)

plt.plot(model.predict(X)[:,0])
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

**Out:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Changing d to 0 seems to fix the problem. What still confuses me is if the model overfits, why isn't the predictions be extremely close to the training true value but off systematically like that?

Comment: @TommyDo Because if you use dropout your model, actually your layers of neurons, overfits only to a portion of the input. So never can overfit on the whole input.